# Why is "respose.paging.next" being returned as Undefined?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

What I am trying to do is, count out the total number of status a user has posted till now. I have currently written this code:

```
function get_status(url){
     FB.api(url, function(response){
     console.log(response);

     var nextpage = response.paging.next; // The error comes from this line
     console.log(nextpage);

     while (nextpage) {
     var path_to_info = String(nextpage).replace('https://graph.facebook.com/','');
     console.log(path_to_info);

     get_status(path_to_info);
     }

    });


}

get_status('me/statuses?fields=message&limit=100');
```

But after showing the result for the 1st time, it says:

```
TypeError: this.paging is undefined
```

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 0):

Your code run OK with the 1st time, but with the 2nd round, the Facebook Graph API return the empty data ( that means you fetched all statuses data at the 1st time, so at the second round, there is no data to show).[image]

So, you need to check whether the response data is empty before getting *response.paging.next*
Hope this help.

Comment: Looks like a new problem... Because when I use it through my account, it shows about 100 posts, then returns No data! but I am sure I have many more posts because I have been using that account for years! :/

Comment: Because it returned No data, so when you used response.paging.next, it will lead to 'this.paging is undefined' error. So, just check whether response is empty before getting response.paging.next.

Are you sure you have more than 100 statuses with your FB account?

Comment: Yes sir, I am 100% sure... I wrote a script for the same purpose with API version 1 and that showed I had 1K+ statuses, But this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You should use offset parameter, in following requests.